# What does "head out the back" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

"OK, You take the keycard and **head out the back**"

It's a sentence from a video game. Me and the other character need to depart quickly cause we are in trouble and need to run from some baddies. I've found a keycard to the door which is located at the back of a building we're in.

definition for "head out" (TFD):

1. To leave some place; to depart.
   Attention, everyone: we're heading out at 10 AM.

I know it probably means to depart through the back door but I don't understand why it's frazed that way. It would make more sense for me if it was "head out out the back" seems to me like the word "out" should be used twice but maybe only to my non-native ear.

Comment: If there's a head lying around, you better take that too.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct, your intuition is less correct.

The phrasal verb "head out" can take a direct object that indicates which exit the person is using:

> He heads out the door.

> He heads out the back.

Comment: I would understand it as a colloquial way of saying _head out [of] the back [door]_.